# Error running a new google v3 api application

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics, google-api, nuget

I recently logged the following forum article asking for help setting up a Google v3 Api application.  I got information back but I am getting an error running the code.
[Google c# Api, changing from v2.3 to v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044576/google-c-sharp-api-changing-from-v2-3-to-v3/20189147#20189147)

Here are the steps I took:

1. Registered a new native application on the google web site
2. Downloaded the client_secrets.json file associated with the application
3. Setup new console app in visual studio 2012 (c#, 4.5)
4. Downloaded the following NuGet packages within my project:

   - install-package google.apis -pre
   - Install-Package Google.Apis.Analytics.v3 -Pre

.
 5. Run the following code:
.

```
UserCredential credential;
     using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream("client_secret.json", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
         {
          credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
          GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
          new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
          "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store")).Result;
          }
```

When I run the code, I get the following error message:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.Desktop, Version=1.0.16.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The dll in question has been registered with the NuGet package install fine and its being copied to the bin/debug folder correctly, so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Same thing happens for me, have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change your .NET version from 4.5 to 4.0.

Comment: Any explanation of why?