# Google c# Api - Access to the path 'Analytics.Auth.Store' is denied

Tags: c#, api, google-analytics

I've been trying to use the Google C# library for API access with the aim of using this with the Analytics API. I've found a few examples of how to make the oAuth call which are consistent ([Google c# Api, changing from v2.3 to v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20044576/google-c-sharp-api-changing-from-v2-3-to-v3/20189147#20189147)) so I've been using this as below:

```
UserCredential credential;

credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "[CLIENT ID]", ClientSecret = "[CLIENT SECRET]" },
new[] { AnalyticsService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
"user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Analytics.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

However, when I run the code in IIS I get the follwing error message:

*Access to the path 'Analytics.Auth.Store' is denied.*

Running the code by debugging in VS2012 Express seems to work as far as I can tell - I get redirected to the approve the authorization request but I can't test it any further as then the redirect URL doesn't match the one I've set in my Google API Project.

Any help greatly appreciated!